# Find the immediate implemented interfaces on a type

Tags: c#, reflection

When calling typeof(Bar).GetInterfaces() on the following scenario the method returns IFoo and IBar.

`interface IFoo {}

interface IBar : IFoo {}

class Bar : IBar {}`

Is there a way that I can find only the immediate interface (IBar) on Bar?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? It sounds to me like a design flaw in your code ;)

Comment: The returned array is non deterministic.

Comment: @Oliver, the system maps interfaces to concrete types. The problem is that another type might be implementing IFoo but we don't want to associate the IFoo interface with the Bar class, but rather the IBar interface.

Comment: Is this your own system? If so, have you considered implementing a kind of registry which is used for the interface-class association? You could also do some convention-over-configuration approach where interface and class name must follow the rule <InterfaceName> = "I" + <ClassName>. Still, I think there is a design flaw, because the class Bar is not only an IBar, but also an IFoo.

Comment: Good question. I found the [best answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5318781) on a different thread.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there's no such thing as the "immediate" interface in the compiled code. Your class is effectively compiled as:

```
class Bar : IBar, IFoo { }
```

and you can't distinguish between the two. The only thing you could do is to check all of them and see whether two or more of the interfaces inherit from each other or not (and even in that case, you can't really check whether the author of the class has explicitly mentioned the base interface in code or not):

```
static IEnumerable<Type> GetImmediateInterfaces(Type type)
{
    var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
    var result = new HashSet<Type>(interfaces);
    foreach (Type i in interfaces)
        result.ExceptWith(i.GetInterfaces());
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IRoo { }
public interface ISoo : IRoo { }
public interface IMoo : ISoo { }
public interface IGoo : IMoo { }
public interface IFoo : IGoo { }
public interface IBar : IFoo { }
public class Bar : IBar { }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Type[] interfaces = typeof(Bar).GetInterfaces();    
    Type immediateInterface = GetPrimaryInterface(interfaces);
    // IBar
}

public Type GetPrimaryInterface(Type[] interfaces)
{
    if (interfaces.Length == 0) return null;
    if (interfaces.Length == 1) return interfaces[0];

    Dictionary<Type, int> typeScores = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
    foreach (Type t in interfaces)
        typeScores.Add(t, 0);

    foreach (Type t in interfaces)
        foreach (Type t1 in interfaces)
            if (t.IsAssignableFrom(t1))
                typeScores[t1]++;

    Type winner = null;
    int bestScore = -1;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, int> pair in typeScores) {
        if (pair.Value > bestScore) {
            bestScore = pair.Value;
            winner = pair.Key;
        }
    }
    return winner;
}
```

Comment: Interesting looking code, but why does `GetPrimaryInterface` return only one interface type?  Seems it would need to potentially return multiple interface types to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This picks out the interface with the longest inheritance tree.

```
typeof(Bar)
  .GetInterfaces()
  .OrderByDescending(i => i.GetInterfaces().Length)
  .FirstOrDefault()
```

It was enough for my use case.