# Finding all Interface that a class implements

Tags: c#, reflection

Can someone tell me how to find all interfaces that a class implements by using C# reflection ?

Like find all classes that implement a specific interface

```
if(type.getInterface(typeof(IAuto)) != null)
{
   console.writeline(type.name.tostring());
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all types that implement an interface with C# 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733/getting-all-types-that-implement-an-interface-with-c-sharp-3-0)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. It's vice versa. It's more like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055411/find-the-immediate-implemented-interfaces-on-a-type

Comment: @Scoregraphic I thought that too, until I saw the example. The title says something different than the example shows. OP, can you clarify? In description: *find all class that implements specific interface* is the opposite of title: *Finding all Interface that a class implements*

Comment: i want to know Finding all Interface that a class implements ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var interfaces = typeof(Classname).GetInterfaces();
```

Comment: @Scoregraphic: I'm not sure about your edit. He wanted all interfaces of the class and not all interfaces which IAuto inherits.

Comment: Switched back to my original solution because I think it fits the question better

Comment: Agreed, my bad! The type is not known.